# Tevo Michelangelo nozzle below build plate?

Tags: nozzle, bed-leveling, build-plate

I got a Tevo Michelangelo as first 3D printer today and already got a problem with the bed leveling: The extruder nozzle is way below the build plate. (When I auto-home the axes, which I've done several times). I thought to just adjust the plate downwards, but it was incredibly slow, and there was almost no progress.

Here's a picture, sorry for the bad quality:

[image: Extruder nozzle below build plate]

Should I continue adjusting it downwoards via the screws (It's getting harder), or is there some other way to solve this? Or am I just making a dumb mistake?

Comment: Doesn't your printer have an adjustable Z-stop switch?  you really don't want to crank down the bed screws for fear of bending the plate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the Z-endstop up a little higher, also make sure the bed leveling screws are not completely screwed in.

So:

1. Move the head of the printer up.
2. Move up the Z-endstop so that the nozzle is a little higher than the build platform.
3. Home the printer.
4. Disable the stepper motors and move the head over the bed to a certain position (e.g. a corner without disturbing the Z axis), once you get to a new position of the bed, raise the bed by unscrewing the screws until a piece of paper shows noticeable drag when pulled between the nozzle and build platform.
5. Goto 3 until you have done all corners several times, also the center of the bed. It is advised to once in a while re-home the printer, this way accidental Z-axis movement is compensated again.

Comment: Thanks, bed is now leveled (Although I have to wait until my filaments coming). Follow-up question: [Does moving the endstop upwards affect the maximum height of the printed object?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/does-moving-the-z-endstop-upwards-affect-the-maximum-height-of-the-printable-obj)